# Git Commit Command Getting an error of path spec

Tags: git

I am getting an error while trying to commit in git. What is the reason? I suppose that everything is ok.

```
farooq@ubuntu:~/workspace/abproject$ git commit -m “First commit of assignment2_farooq”
error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'of' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'abproject”' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: It looks like you're using some sort of typographical quotation marks instead of the quotation marks the shell expects (`"` or `'`).

Comment: what does  `git status` show? did you do a `git add .` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes you're entering in there aren't the normal quotes for your terminal.  If you want to use the `-m` flag, then you have to use proper quotes `" "` instead.

It's actually better practice to not use the `-m` flag instead, as you're limited in the number of characters you can write in that window.  Omit it, and use the `core.editor` to write your commit messages instead.

Comment: Aagain failed to execute the commit command now getting this error . I have a git repository cofigured with ssh key.                  farooq@ubuntu:~/workspace/assignment2_farooqab$ git commit -m "This is first commit "

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'farooq@ubuntu.(none)')
farooq@ubuntu:~/workspace/assignment2_farooqab$

Comment: That's not an error; you have to enter in your email and name before you commit.  Do what the command prompt tells you and you'll be fine.

Comment: I put the Username and email and it works. i can commit in repository.  My university git is not fancy . I cant see my repository in University servers. Why is that.. I can commit using the Linux Terminal. But can not see my project in Personal unversity git website